# PHP PDO MSSQL SP - no return values

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I need some help in relation to PHP PDO MSSQL Stored Procedure.

I have a Stored Procedure which is called with two parameters `userId` and `pwd`, the Stored Procedure then returns two values `status` and `token` (using `SELECT @status as status, null as token` in the Stored Procedure to return the value)

When I try to call the Stored Procedure from PHP (ver. 7.0) using PDO I don't receive any return values

This is the PHP code:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$db_name, 
$username,$password);

$userId = "2465";   
$pwd = "460";

$query = "exec sp_getToken @userId=:userId, @pwd=:pwd";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId);
$stmt->bindValue(':pwd', $pwd);

$stmt->execute();

while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Can anyone tell what to do?

Comment: simple; you never executed the query.

Comment: Ups it must have slipped in the copy I have $stmt->execute(); between the last bindValue and the while loop

Comment: update your post then and check for errors and the logs. You're not doing that.

Comment: actually; I should have phrased my first comment as: *"where is the `execute()`?"*. My bad.

Comment: TBH, I don't know what's causing your code to not be working. Can you check for errors with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (set to catch and display) and a possibility to try and change the `bindValue()` to `bindParam()`.

Comment: Can you do another update to your question (please) as to what the schema is, the column types and example values? It will probably help in many ways. If you feel that is irrelevant, then see the answer below.

Comment: I'm also wondering if you did close this off `$stmt->execute()` it's missing a semi-colon. If that is your actual code, then php would have caught that as parse error and should read as `$stmt->execute();` << - Your question is starting to look very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same, but you may try with this:

```
<?php
$host = 'server\instance,port';
$db_name = 'database';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';

# Connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$db_name, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: ".$e->getMessage());
}

# Stored procedure
try {
    $query = "{call sp_getToken(@userId=?, @pwd=?)}";
    $userId = "2465";   
    $pwd = "460";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        var_dump($result);
        echo"</br>";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error executing stored procedure: ".$e->getMessage());
}
$stmt = null;

#
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - it didn't solved the problem directly, but by running the code, I got another error message (Error executing stored procedure: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.) - which did help me to find a solution to problem. 

The problem was that a stored procedure returns a result containing the number of rows affected as the first result and then the actual result. By adding "SET NOCOUNT ON" in my stored procedure the first row is skipped.

Comment: @hedemann I'm glad, that you have found a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solves :)

By adding "SET NOCOUNT ON" to my stored procedure. Obviously the problem was related to the facts, that a stored procedure returns two results, the first result containing the number of rows affected and the second result containing the actual data.

Thanks to everybody for trying helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are stored in the database schema I believe.

If you add the schema to your query SQL server should know where to "look" for your stored procedure.

```
$query = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_getToken] @userId=:userId, @pwd=:pwd";
```

Also when binding the parameters it might help defining the type. I've had issues with SQL server where defining the parameter typed resolved the issue.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Also, make sure that the user that PHP logs into the database has the Execute permission in SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

> In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and then expand that instance.
>
> Expand Databases, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand Programmability.
>
> Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure to grant permissions on, and then click Properties.
>
> From Stored Procedure Properties, select the Permissions page.
>
> To grant permissions to a user, database role, or application role, click Search.
>
> In Select Users or Roles, click Object Types to add or clear the users and roles you want.
>
> Click Browse to display the list of users or roles. Select the users or roles to whom permissions should be granted.
>
> In the Explicit Permissions grid, select the permissions to grant to the specified user or role. For a description of the permissions, see Permissions (Database Engine).
>
> Selecting Grant indicates the grantee will be given the specified permission.
> Selecting Grant With indicates that the grantee will also be able to grant the specified permission to other principals.

Comment: I agree that by adding the types as an argument helps, however we don't know what their schema looks like, or the column types and respective values are. The user id one is most likely an int type, but the password column's type is questionable. I feel the question lacks a lot of detail. An int type for a probable text type will fail on `PARAM_INT`, *just saying*.

Comment: True, but we can depend on OP to define the proper types. A password field would be an nvarchar type so a string I would think, but one never knows. But if it's an int or something else OP will have to modify it himself.

Comment: I've posted a comment asking for it. I'll come back later to see how this is unraveling ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: the userId and pwd is of type varchar(50) (old system) - I have now added "PDO::PARAM_STR" to both bindValue - result still the same

Comment: yes - but should the $db_name in the "$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$db_name, 
$username,$password);" do the same job

Comment: Not per se. One database can have multiple schemas with different access to different priveleges. Check under which schema the stored procedure is made

Comment: @hedemann does that comment mean it works now or that it still doesn't work? Also check that the database user you're logging into to the database has the Execute permission

Comment: @hedemann have you tried checking the permissions like I edited in my update?

Comment: The permissions for the user is alright, have no problems in executing the SP